# Javascript Data Structures

Tags: javascript

How can I store player names and scores in a way that is easy to set, retrieve and update? Arrays, objects etc? What are the pro's and con's? Which is more extensible?

I was thinking something like

```
Players {
    [Dan : 500]
    [Jess: 600]
    [Elvis: 56]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects have an advantage over key-value pairs in that they are extensible. You can store more attrbutes

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Answer (score 4):

Key-value stores in Javascript are objects:

```
var players = {
    Dan   : 500,
    Jess  : 600,
    Elvis : 56
};

players.Dan = 300;
alert(players.Jess);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var Players = {}; 

// adding new player.
Players["Dan"] = 0; 

// push score
Players.Dan += 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Objects would serve your purpose :

eg:

```
var players = { "Dan" : 500 , "Jess" : 600 , "Elvis" : 56 }
```

You can easily access values using key.

eg

```
alert(players["Dan"]);
```

see this example : http://jsfiddle.net/PQxHM/